# Android how to add extra text while sharing url

Tags: android

I want to add a feature in an android app to share url via email & facebook , I am using following piece of code ,

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content );
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share article"));
```

While sharing it via email I want content string to contain 
content = someurl + ( Shared via MyApp )
whereas while sharing via Facebook I want to use
content = someurl

as Facebook refuses to recognize the url if I add anything to it .

can anyone help me with problem as how I can achieve both ?

Comment: use "text/html" instead of text/plain

Comment: @Rajesh no use, now facebook option disappears on text/html